# Why is "gdb" listing multiple functions after executing the "start' command even when the C++ source file doesn't contain any function?

Tags: c++, gdb

## The context

Consider the following file

```
$ cat main.cpp
int main() {return 0;}
```

I can list all the available functions by executing

```
$ g++ -g main.cpp && gdb -q -batch -ex 'info functions -n' a.out
```

```
All defined functions:

File main.cpp:
1:      int main();
```

When executing `start` before executing `info functions` more than 1000 functions are listed (see below)

```
g++ -g main.cpp && \
  gdb -q -batch -ex 'start' -ex 'info functions -n' a.out | \
  head -n 10
```

```
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x111d: file main.cpp, line 1.

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:1
1   int main() {return 0;}
All defined functions:

File /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/allocated_ptr.h:
70: void std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error::_Impl, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error::_Impl>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr();
70: void std::__allocated_ptr<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::filesystem::filesystem_error::_Impl, std::allocator<std::filesystem::filesystem_error::_Impl>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::~__allocated_ptr();
```

As seen below, the total number of lines printed is so, apparently, more than 1000 functions are being listed

```
g++ -g main.cpp && gdb -q -batch -ex 'start' -ex 'info functions -n' a.out | wc -l
4436
```

## The question

As we can see above, the `main.cpp` file does not contain any function, so why is `gdb` listing those functions when the `start` command has been executed before but not when `start` hasn't been executed?

## Additional context

As suggested in one of the comments of this question, here's the output of executing `info shared` after `start` has been executed

```
g++ -g main.cpp && gdb -q -batch -ex 'start' -ex 'info shared' a.out
```

```
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x111d: file main.cpp, line 1.

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:1
1   int main() {return 0;}
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7fd2090  0x00007ffff7ff2746  Yes (*)     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007ffff7e4c040  0x00007ffff7f37b52  Yes         /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
0x00007ffff7c7f3b0  0x00007ffff7d1a658  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/libm.so.6
0x00007ffff7c59020  0x00007ffff7c69ca5  Yes         /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
0x00007ffff7ab3650  0x00007ffff7bfe6bd  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

Comment: Perhaps those are the functions defined in the standard library, which is linked to your program by default?

Comment: After you run `start`, can you also run `info shared` and show us the output?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The output of the `info shared` command has been added to the question.

Comment: Here's a kind of hacky workaround, since you're using the `-n` option, which tells gdb to show only the functions found in debuginfo: you can make gdb fail to find the debuginfo files for standard shared libraries by doing something like `set debug-file-directory /nonexistent` before starting the program. (Tested on CentOS.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> main.cpp file does not contain any function, so why is gdb listing those functions when the start command has been executed before but not when start hasn't been executed?

Before `start`, GDB reads symbols (and debug info) only for the main executable.

After `start`, a dynamically linked executable loads shared libraries (seen in `info shared`), and GDB (by default) reads symbol tables and debug info for each of them. And since these libraries contain hundreds of functions, GDB knows about all of them.

You can prevent this with `set auto-solib-add off`, but *usually* you don't want to do that. If you do, and your program crashes in e.g. `abort`, GDB will not know where you crashed *unless* you manually add the symbols back using `sharedlibrary` or `add-symbol-file` [command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html).